# Yii URL pattern issue

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting

I have a url pattern defined as below for a REST API build using yii.

```
      'urlManager'=>array(
      'urlFormat'=>'path',
      'rules'=>array(
                      array('api/default/list', 'pattern'=>'api/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
                      array('api/default/view', 'pattern'=>'api/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
                      array('api/default/update', 'pattern'=>'api/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
                      array('api/default/delete', 'pattern'=>'api/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
                      array('api/default/create', 'pattern'=>'api/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),
      '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
      ),
      ),
```

What i am trying now is,

http://example.com/RestApi/index.php/**api/post?offset=5&limit=10**

The above works, but the following doesnt work.

http://example.com/RestApi/index.php/**api/post/offset/5/limit/10**

How can i make it work like second way? what changes needs to be done to the Url Manager ?

Thanks

**Update**

The error i get for second way is,

Unable to resolve the request "api/post/offset/5/limit/10".

Comment: Did you set up your .htaccess file

Comment: @crafter nope. i didnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 'urlManager'=>array(
      'urlFormat'=>'path',
      'rules'=>array(
                      array('api/default/view', 'pattern'=>'api/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>/*', 'verb'=>'GET'),

                      array('api/default/list', 'pattern'=>'api/<model:\w+>/*', 'verb'=>'GET'),

            .............
      ),
  ),
```

I moved `api/default/view` rule to avoid overwriting another rules.

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt trigger the way i need,  for example, url 1 - http://localhost/RestApi/index.php/api/user/ | url 2 http://localhost/RestApi/index.php/api/user/1 . url 1 works with any number of addition parameters but url 2 doesnt work at all because firs change overrides the url 2 pattern.